How do I fix error TS2769: No overload matches this call. I have exhausted the resources online but I can't get it fixed
I'm having a problem wih my typescript file in the controllers folder for the backend when I run npm run dev in the terminal details of the error:
 No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<express.Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<express.Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Type 'Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
          Type 'Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
            Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void'.
              Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'void'.

7 router.post("/", jwtCheck, MyUserController.createCurrentUser);
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:153:5
    153     <
            ~
    154         P = ParamsDictionary,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ... 
    162         ...handlers: Array<RequestHandlerParams<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, LocalsObj>>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    163     ): T;
        ~~~~~~~~~
    The last overload is declared here.

    at createTSError (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/ben-willys/Desktop/nai-eats-app/backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2769 ]
}

MyUserController.ts
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import User from "../models/user";

const createCurrentUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    // check if user exists
try {
    const { auth0Id } = req.body;
    const  existingUser = await User.findOne({ auth0Id });
    
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(200).send();
    }

    const newUser = new User(req.body);
    await newUser.save();

    res.status(201).json(newUser.toObject());
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating user"});
}
};

export default { createCurrentUser, };


This is how Icall createCurrentUser in MyUserRoute.ts
import express from "express";

import MyUserController from "../controllers/MyUserController";
import { jwtCheck } from "../middleware/auth";
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", jwtCheck, MyUserController.createCurrentUser);
export default router;

It looks like the exception origin is some file where you call createCurrentUser. No overloads match the required profile createCurrentUser with the types Request and Response. But you don't show this piece of code. At least, did you check it yourself?

@SergeyAKryukov the file where I call createCurrentUser is MyUserRoute.ts:  import express from "express";
import MyUserController from "../controllers/MyUserController";
import { jwtCheck } from "../middleware/auth";
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", jwtCheck, MyUserController.createCurrentUser);
export default router;

@SergeyAKryukov in this block 'const createCurrentUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {.....' when I use express directly as follows const createCurrentUser = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {.....' the error seem to disappear but it is shown again in the terminal after running npm run dev

Thank you for the replies. But instead of addressing these comments to me, you would need to improve your question and clarify everything.  As to your comments to me, just a notification would be enough.

@SergeyAKryukov about the file containing the exception, yes checked on it. But the ts error is still there. I am newbie in programming though

Ben, I still cannot see the code where you call createCurrentUser. Where you import and call. You only show where you define and export it.

You should type createCurrentUser. You'll see that it does not honour RequestHandler.

@EricMORAND thanks for your contribution, I downgraded the type/express from the latest to version 4 and it cleared the error.
